# Loading multiple config file from spring cloud config server

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud

Hey I got to know how to check properties in config server i.e. **http://{Config server URL}:{Port}/{ServiceID}/{Profile}**

Right now I am facing a problem where I've to read multiple properties file from cloud config server. Ex: Right now I've to read properties file(huge file) from a single property file i.e. employee.properties

I don't want huge list of properties file in single folder. like

```
employee-dev.properties
employee-dit.properties
employee-sit.properties
employee-uat.properties
employee-preprod.properties
employee-prod.properties

customers-dev.properties
customers-dit.properties
customers-sit.properties
customers-uat.properties
customers-preprod.properties
customers-prod.properties

.
.
.
and soo on.
```

My requirement is I need to maitain a list of properties file and config server will provide me these values. like :

```
**{env}/employee.properties**
**{env}/customers.properties**
```

Here env could be any environment like dit, sit, prod etc.

Hope I'll get answer here.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to have all properties files in an only folder, so you need to add this configuration on config server properties file.

**1. Match all options**

```
spring.cloud.config.server.native.searchLocations = [classpath:/, classpath:/config, classpath:/config/{application}, classpath:/config/{application}/{profile}]
```

**2. Match only /application-name/application-name-profile.properties**

```
spring.cloud.config.server.native.searchLocations = classpath:config/{application}
```

Then you'll have matched based on application name folder for example.
 resources/config/application-name/application-name-properties.